# Javascript - Help moving between 2 Arrays/Stacks

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, list, stack

I have 2 Arrays and a Variable. I am able to push an item into a variable, and then on a second click, add it to an Array. However, i have another button that moves an item from that Array, back into the Variable and move the variable into another Array. 
My code works on the first section, however my function does now load for the second, any help please?

It is this section that does not seem to work

```
<INPUT type=button value="Back" onClick='txtPop.value = popBackStack();showStack(theList);pushForStack(curUrl);
showStack2(theList2);'>
```

The whole code is below:

```
<SCRIPT>
    var backStack = new Array();
    var forStack = new Array();
    var curUrl = document.getElementById("txtPop");

    function pushStack(newVal) {
      backStack.push(curUrl);
      curUrl = newVal;
    }

    function pushForStack(newVal) {
      CurUrl = newVal;
      forstack.push(curUrl);
    }

    function popBackStack() {
      var popVal = backStack.pop();
      if (popVal == undefined) return "Nothing left!";
      else return popVal
    }

    function popForStack() {
      var popVal = forStack.pop();
      if (popVal == undefined) return "Enter a new URL";
      else return popVal;
    }

    function showStack(theSelect) {
      theSelect.options.length = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < backStack.length; i++) {
        var theOption = new Option(backStack[i]);
        theSelect.options[theSelect.options.length] = theOption;
      }
    }

    function showStack2(theSelect) {
      theSelect.options.length = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < forStack.length; i++) {
        var theOption = new Option(forStack[i]);
        theSelect.options[theSelect.options.length] = theOption;
      }
    }
 </SCRIPT>

<table width="104%" height="364" border="5" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
<tr>
<th width="30%" height="78" scope="col"><p>
<INPUT type=button value="Back" onClick='txtPop.value =     popBackStack();showStack(theList);pushForStack(curUrl);
showStack2(theList2);'></p></th>
<th width="46%" scope="col"><p>
<center>
<INPUT type=text name=txtPush>
<INPUT type=button value="Push"   onClick='pushStack(txtPush.value);txtPush.value="";txtPop.value = curUrl;   showStack(theList);'>
</center>
</p></th>
<th width="24%" scope="col"><p><INPUT type=button value="Forward" onClick="txtPop.value      = popBackStack();showStack2(theList2);"></p></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p><center>
<SELECT name="theList" size=12>
</SELECT>
</center></p></td>
<td><p><center><INPUT type=textki name=txtPop size=25></center></p></td>
<td><center>
<SELECT name="theList2" size=12>
</SELECT>
</center></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yikes! That's a lot of javascript to push into an HTML attribute. You'll find life a lot easier if you put that code into a javascript function and then call that function on the click event... either by using that html attribute, or by explicitly adding the handler in document onLoad code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems in your code

1. The call `document.getElementById('txtPop')` ought to be returning nothing, since you have no elements with that ID. You have an element with that *name*, but not *id*.
2. You're trying to push `curUrl` into the stacks, but `curUrl` (when correctly initialised) is an element, not a value... I don't believe that's what you're trying to do.
3. Your click handlers are way too complicated to be putting into element attributes. Put them into their own functions and then attach them using the function name... take a look at some tutorials on Event handling for better ways to do this, such as www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript. **PLEASE** do not follow a w3schools tutorial. They are worse than bad.